# how to use object of structure with constructure in another structure?

Tags: c++

I have a structure with two constructor that has a byte* member as following :

```
struct structA
{
   byte* pData;  int nLength;

  structA()
  {
    pData = NULL; nLength = 0;
  }

  structA(int nLen)
  {
    pData = new byte[nLen];  nLength = nLen;
  }

  ~structA()
  {
    delete[] pData;
  }
}
```

Another structure namely structB has a list of structA:

```
struct structB
{
  CList <structA, structA&> AList;
}
```

Now i create an object of structA with parameter 10 as input and add it to an object of structB:

//start of scope

```
structA osA(10);
structB osB;
osB.AList.AddTail(osA);
```

//end of scope

The problem is that when the program exit from the scope, destructure of structA is called 2 times and program crashes.

what is the problem and why it occurs?
any help is apperciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy constructor (or a move constructor).  The compiler default copy constructor will just copy the pointer, and then both objects will delete the same pointer when you exit.

Comment: what's the copy constructure?

Comment: Google "copy constructor" or read your textbook (or buy a textbook if you don't have one).  It's not something that's really suitable for a SO answer.